# Horizontal Line in footer which ignores the margin

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

How can I add a horizontal line in the footer which spans the entire width of the page?

```
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

is giving a line which is inside the margin only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the `\footrule` macro provided by [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Here's a possible way:

```
\makeatletter
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\footrulewidth}}
    \vskip\footruleskip}}
\makeatother
```

In a regular document, this should jump left (negative `\hspace`) far enough to land outside the page border, then set a horizontal `\rule` of width `\footrulewidth` that is twice the width of the paper (ensuring it spans across the entire page).

Here's a working example showing a regular page and the updated footer rule on page 2 (the above change is done mid-document, but you'll want to add it to your preamble for a global effect on your document):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\begin{document}
Stuff

\clearpage

\makeatletter
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\footrulewidth}}
    \vskip\footruleskip}}
\makeatother

Stuff
\end{document}
```